# Best simple and effective solution for data organization

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-analysis

I'm new with Python programming so I'm doing a bunch of practice exercise in order to improve my skills.
Therefore, I would like to show you guys my approach on this example and if you could let me know what you think I would be grateful!

Exercise:
Given a list of costumers IDs, I have to segment them by the following logic:

- If ID is multiple of 7 and multiple of 3 then segment 'A'
- If ID is multiple of 3 then segment 'B'
- If ID is multiple of 7, then segment 'C'
- Else, segment 'D'

What I've done:

```
from collections import Counter
from datetime import datetime
import os.path
import json

date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

customer_indices = [list of IDs] ex: [123981,12398,123157,12371...]


def segment(customer):
    if customer % 7 == 0 & customer % 3 == 0:
        return 'A'
    elif customer % 7 == 0:
        return 'B'
    elif customer % 3 == 0:
        return 'C'
    else:
        return 'D'


def split_customers(customers):
    a = []
    b = []
    c = []
    d = []

    for customer in customers:
        if customer % 7 == 0 & customer % 3 == 0:
            a.append(customer)
        elif customer % 7 == 0:
            b.append(customer)
        elif customer % 3 == 0:
            c.append(customer)
        else:
            d.append(customer)
    return a,b,c,d

segmentation = [segment(customer) for customer in customer_indices]

print('Segmentation list: ')
print(segmentation)
print('\n')


segmentation_counter = Counter(segmentation)

print('Count of clients per segment: ')
print(f"A: {segmentation_counter['A']}")
print(f"B: {segmentation_counter['B']}")
print(f"C: {segmentation_counter['C']}")
print(f"D: {segmentation_counter['D']}")


a, b, c, d = split_customers(customer_indices)


main_dict = {'Date': date,
             'Segmentation': {
                 'A Clients': {
                     'Count': segmentation_counter['A'],
                     'Customers': a},
                 'B Clients': {
                     'Count': segmentation_counter['B'],
                     'Customers': b},
                 'C Clients': {
                     'Count': segmentation_counter['C'],
                     'Customers': c},
                 'D Clients': {
                     'Count': segmentation_counter['D'],
                     'Customers': d}}}


main_list = [main_dict]

if not os.path.exists('Data/customer_segmentation.json'):
    os.makedirs('Data')

if os.path.isfile('Data/customer_segmentation.json'):
    with open('Data/customer_segmentation.json') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        file.close()

    data.append(main_dict)
    with open('Data/customer_segmentation.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=2)
        file.close()

else:
    file = open('Data/customer_segmentation.json', 'w')
    json.dump(main_list, file, indent=2)
    file.close()
```

The original code has a with open txt function at first that extracts the client's ID list from a txt within the same directory of this .py

The main idea of this solution it would be to execute this every day so the json file will update with a new list for each day that it's run, so if I want to do an analysis of the segmentation growth, it would be pretty easy to do so.

What do you think?

Comment: I have just realized that for the segmentation list I can do either list comprehension like in the example or list(map(segment,customer_indices)), which is better?

Comment: Have a look into `pandas`, specifically a `pandas.DataFrame`.  It's an powerful and flexible data structure which you might find useful.